# Mysql HAVING clause with condition if it is possible

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I would like to know if the following HAVING clause is valid

```
SELECT
  m.id,
  m.username,
  m.name,
  m.department,
  dp.department as dep,
  dp.id,
  (
    SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `time` ) ) )
    FROM time_management tm
    WHERE 
      tm.user = m.id
      AND MONTH(`date`) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
      AND YEAR(`date`)= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
  ) as time
FROM
  members m 
  LEFT JOIN department dp ON m.department = dp.id   
WHERE m.department = $departmentvar
HAVING (($key - time) > 34)
```

in this case `$key = 100`

```
time = 5:00:00
```

The idea is to select only results which satisfies the condition that their time is not enough , for example

display results which have `time = 5:00:00` because (100-5) = 95 > 34 
but does not display results which have `time = 95:00:00` because (100-95) = 5 > 34
for example ?

Comment: 100 - 95:00:00 != 100-95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to include expressions in a HAVING clause.

But MySQL isn't going to know what to do with the token `$key`, if that's part of the SQL text being sent.

Perhaps the client program is doing some variable substitution to generate a string, and that `$key` is getting replaced with `100` in the string that is going to be sent to MySQL... that's an assumption we're likely to make here. But  it's an assumption.  It appears that you are asking about the SQL statement that is being sent to MySQL.

---

As far as returning only rows where "time is not enough", it's certainly possible to have that condition in the HAVING clause.

The `time` column in the resultset is going to be datatype TIME.

But I'm confused by this construct...

```
  100 - time  > 34
```

Why would be subtracting TIME datatype from a numeric literal?

If we want to compare the TIME datatype, it would make more sense to compare that to another TIME datatype, or convert the TIME into a number of seconds.

(It's not at all clear what the `100` and `34` represent.)

Seems like you want to do something like:

```
 HAVING time < '01:06:00'
```

or

```
 HAVING time < SEC_TO_TIME(( 100 - 34 )*60)
```

Or

```
 HAVING ( 100 - TIME_TO_SEC(time) ) > 34
```

It's not clear what you are attempting to achieve, so those are just some patterns that appear to be more valid than the original.

Comment: Hello Spencer,  $key = 100 represents variable which calculates working hours for each day in a month. for example. today is 3 of January this is second working day so key will be 8x2 = 16 hours this is why it is in number and not TIME datatype, since I don't know if there is conversion in mysql to convert 5:00:00 -> to 5 hours so then it will be 16 - 5 = 11 hours are left to be completed so far for this month for up today date. and 34 is 20% of 176 working hours per month. so the task is to select all results which have more than 20% left hours

Comment: Have converted Key to seconds and it works excellent. Thank you!